# Unable to name log file with custom timestamp format using TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, logging, rollover

Is it possible to create log files with custom date format, using `TimedRotatingFileHandler`?

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import os
from datetime import datetime
import time

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

log_dir = 'logs'
log_file = os.path.join(log_dir, datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') + f'_.log')

handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file, when='s', interval=1, backupCount=0)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)

i = 0
while True:
    logger.info(i)
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1
```

Produces

```
20230810-100547_.log.2023-08-10_10-05-47
20230810-100547_.log.2023-08-10_10-05-48
20230810-100547_.log
```

Instead of

```
20230810-100547_.log
20230810-100548_.log
20230810-100549_.log
```

Does one need to reset the handler after midnight (is it even possible)? Does not seem elegant.

There seem to be a [namer attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.BaseRotatingHandler.namer) in logging handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `rotation_filename` method and you can assign it to namer function. It will change name of your log file during rotation. Working code should look like this:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import os
from datetime import datetime
import time

def namer(self):
    now = datetime.now()
    log_dir = './logs'
    return os.path.join(log_dir, datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') + f'_.log')

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

log_dir = './logs'
log_file = os.path.join(log_dir, datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') + f'_.log')

handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file, when='s', interval=1, backupCount=0)
handler.rotation_filename = namer
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)


i = 0
while True:
    logger.info(i)
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks - this is a big help! One question: every time an interval is reached, it renames existing log file and creates new log file one conforming to initial `log_file` string. Could it avoid the renaming step? With daily log, you know after midnight the final name of log (`YYYYMMDD.log`).

Comment: To my knowledge - no. As far I understand Rotating loggers in python, they work like this:
1. Create a "log" file
2. When interval is reached rename existing "log" file to e.g. "log.1" file and create new "log" file.

Maybe there is a workaround by using non rotating logger and creating new handler every interval, but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: I am now wondering if with midnight interval, it will name the log for yesterday with today's timestamp. I guess one can remove 1 day in `namer` function. Thanks again!

Comment: @jlipinski you have it almost right, but not quite You shouldn't monkey-patch the rotation_filename method, but set the namer attribute - `handler.namer = custom_namer_func` - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.BaseRotatingHandler.namer